Need exact JSON response that I see in Neo4j Browser (when I click on Table at the left), with Python driver, for Neo4J dijkstra
I am new to Neo4J. I experimented with the Neo4J browser. I ran a dijkstra route search. I liked the JSON output that I got on the Neo4J browser. I am not getting the same with the Python driver. How can I get something like below with the python driver?
{
  "start": {
    "identity": 45,
    "labels": [
      "Station"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "name": "Krantiveera Sangolli Rayanna railway station"
    },
    "elementId": "4:2e85c3c1-88de-4646-8e7a-59190fb4b184:45"
  },
  "end": {
    "identity": 15,
    "labels": [
      "Station"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "name": "Mantri Square Sampige Road"
    },
    "elementId": "4:2e85c3c1-88de-4646-8e7a-59190fb4b184:15"
  },
  "segments": [...


You are asking about path results. See this answer to a similar question for nodes. A similar (but more complex) approach would work for paths, but may not be worth it.
